# Start search on Enter using React material-table

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I'm new to using React and material-table and am trying to sort out how to initiate search after the user presses Enter. I've been able to find the `debounceInterval` option, but the API I am using to search remote data currently does not return partial matches so I'd like the user to press "Enter" when they want the search to start.

Using `monitorEvents($0)` I can see that there is a `keydown` Event on the element `input.MuiInputBase-input.MuiInput-input.MuiInputBase-inputAdornedStart.MuiInputBase-inputAdornedEnd` but I'm not sure how to add an event listener here or is there is an option to specify which `event.target.value` to use to start the search. The material-table Search code is here: https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/blob/master/src/components/m-table-toolbar.js

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
<TextField
  onKeyPress={(ev) => {
   console.log(`Pressed keyCode ${ev.key}`);
    if (ev.key === 'Enter') {
  // Do code here
     ev.preventDefault();
    }
  }}
  />
```

Comment: Thanks, in material-table I don't know what the search field element is or then how to use the Enter event to start the search. Have you used this?

Comment: What about set ref of search  textfield and check the current with event.target in keypress event.

Comment: Can you put some online sample for your problem.